# Indexes on content delivery servers stopped updating on publish end

Tags: indexing, events

Some day both indexes on  content delivery servers stopped updating (on publish end). I have searched the internet, "failed requests tracing" is not enabled, the `default\anonymous` user has read access in web db and tried the https://github.com/sitecoresupport/Sitecore.Support.404817/releases

```
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole(String username, String roleName)
   at Sitecore.Security.Accounts.RolesInRolesProvider.IsUserInRole(User user, Role targetRole, Boolean includeIndirectMemberships)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AccessRule.RuleApplies(Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType, Boolean includeRoleMembers, Boolean includeEveryoneMembers)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AccessRuleCollectionHelper.GetMatchingRule(Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType, AccessPermission permission, Boolean includeRoleMembers, Boolean includeEveryoneMembers)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AccessRuleCollectionHelper.GetMatchingRule(Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Buckets.Security.AuthenticationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetAncestorAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Buckets.Security.AuthenticationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetAncestorAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Buckets.Security.AuthenticationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetAncestorAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Buckets.Security.AuthenticationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetAncestorAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Buckets.Security.AuthenticationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetAncestorAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Buckets.Security.AuthenticationHelper.GetItemAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight, PropagationType propagationType)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAuthorizationHelper.GetAccess(Item item, Account account, AccessRight accessRight)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationProvider.GetAccess(ISecurable entity, Account account, AccessRight accessRight)
   at Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationManager.IsAllowed(ISecurable entity, AccessRight right, Account account)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.ApplySecurity(Item item, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.GetItem(ID itemId, Language language, Version version, Database database)
   at Sitecore.Data.TemplateRecords.GetTemplate(ID templateID, Language language)
   at Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.get_Template()
   at Sitecore.Caching.RuleCache.RemoveFromCache(Item item, Func`1 getParentFunc)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSavedRemote(Object sender, ItemSavedRemoteEventArgs args)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Sitecore.Eventing.EventProvider.RaiseEvent(Object event, Type eventType, EventContext context)
```

Comment: What index update strategy are you using? Is the error you have shared from the crawling logs? Do you see references to indexing process starting in crawling log? Have you made any changes to web DB recently? Have you removed any roles?

Comment: OnPublishEndAsync, no from the log.txt No, No, no, it stoped one day without any change in the system

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `default\Anonymous` user is corrupted. I overrided the `RaiseQueuedEvents` method and switched the context user to `extranet\Anonymous` for all events. It works fine now.
Set the new provider in the next tag:

```
add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Eventing.EventProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" systemDatabaseName="core"
```